# Is it possible to separate a C# executable and its dependent dlls in different folder and run the application?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, dll

I am working on a feasibility task, where it is required to keep a C# - WPF application in a folder and to keep its dependency dlls in a separate folder. Is it possible to do dynamic loading ?

When I investigated I found that .NET assemblies should be placed in a common directory/sub directories due to security reasons, otherwise it wont work. My requirement is to separate them in a different drive-folder.

Can you suggest a solution for this?

Comment: So long as the DLLs are on some path that is searched for DLLs then it should work.. what is the overall goal here?

Comment: What are you trying to *achieve* here? would a single-file deployment be a better option? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible according https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/probing-element?redirectedfrom=MSDN. You will have to update your configuration file (app.config which gets copied to your.exe.config) with something like this:

```
<configuration>  
 <runtime>  
   <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">  
      <probing privatePath="bin;bin2\subbin;bin3"/>  
   </assemblyBinding>  
 </runtime>  
</configuration>
```

Comment: If we use probing, it only specifies subdirectories of the application's base directory right ?
What if my folder structure is like this:

C# executable folder: C:\\Program Files\\TestApplication and
Dependent Dlls folder: C:\\Libs\\Dependencies

. Is it possible to do so in this case ?

Comment: Give it a try. All you have to do it is to update the configuration.